# SQL REGEXP_CONTAINS with dot - Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Working on Google BigQuery, kinda newbie.

I'm trying to capture if in a field there a string like "LS" or "L.S".

So far i've written this piece of code:
IF (REGEXP_CONTAINS(subfamilia_ds, "LS") = true OR REGEXP_CONTAINS(subfamilia_ds, "L.S") = true,true,false) = true THEN "LS"

However, for some reason that goes beyond my SQL knowledge, it's returning values such as "OUTROS MOLUSCOS BALCAO" that as neither "LS" nor "L.S".

I'm really struggling with this, and maybe it's a "dumb" issue.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex pattern you want to match `LS` or `L.S` is either `L\.?S` or `L[.]?S`.  The middle dot is optional, and also it is a regex *metacharacter* which has a special meaning of any single character, and hence it must be escaped to mean a literal dot.  Try this updated version:

```
IF (REGEXP_CONTAINS(subfamilia_ds, "L\\.?S") = true) THEN "LS"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was the other version that you gave me but it worked!                         IF (REGEXP_CONTAINS(subfamilia_ds, "L[.]?S") = true) THEN "LS"